# Null pointer Exception in Java when assigning value to int array

Tags: java

My code shows null pointer exception when i assign values to int array in the object:

```
public class Cage {
    int Value;  
    String Operator;
    int[] placeHolders;
}

Cage o = new Cage();                
o.Value = Integer.parseInt(strSplit[0]);
o.Operator = strSplit[1];               
for(int i=2;i<strSplit.length;i++) {
    o.placeHolders[i] = Integer.parseInt(strSplit[i]);
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialise `placeHolders` so it is not `null`?

Comment: You should read the [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) section of the Java Tutorial, especially the parts about *Declaring a Variable to Refer to an Array* and then *Creating, Initializing, and Accessing an Array*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create an `int` array for your `placeHolders`, it's just a declaration, not a definition right now.

```
o.placeHolders = new int[strSplit.length];
```

Comment: You could make the size of the array `strSplit.length - 2` as the first 2 elements from `strSplit` don't go in `placeHolders`.

Comment: But in that case the array index should changed, in the example it's not zero based.

Comment: Yep, so I suppose it just depends on whether the OP wants a gap at the start of the array.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you want to have `placeHolders` to hold values without `null` values in the first to indexes.

```
o.placeHolders = new int[strSplit.length - 2];
for (int i = 0; i < strSplit.length - 2; i++) {
    o.placeHolders[i] = Integer.parseInt(strSplit[i + 2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate the int[] object before using it:

```
int[] placeHolders = new int[100];
```

Comment: int[100] is hard coding.. i guess not a very good style . thx for helping though

Comment: @V.J. The you should use a list: List<Integer> placeHolders = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Comment: But in this case an array is fine because you know the size required from the length of `strSplit`.

Comment: @mikej then you instantiate the array object with that particular length; anyway, the problem was that the object was not instantiated.